# Send email with an attachment in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, email-attachments

I am trying to send an email with attachment that is saved on SDCard on the emulator but the problem is it send the email without the attachment on it. Please show me where did I go wrong

Here is the code

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] 
                {"djkgotsod@gmail.com"}); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
                "Dear Sir"); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                "Im doing Android");                 
                Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sPhotoUri=" + Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/../.."+getFilesDir()+"/"+myfile));

                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/../.."+getFilesDir()+"/"+myfile));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

---

Here is my log cat

```
01-20 17:59:04.927: E/Trace(31078): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-20 17:59:06.117: D/gralloc_goldfish(31078): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-20 17:59:08.917: V/Main(31078): sPhotoUri=/mnt/sdcard/../../data/data/com.example.emailandroid/files//mnt/sdcard/myfile.csv
01-20 17:59:10.077: I/Choreographer(31078): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-20 17:59:15.267: I/Choreographer(31078): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

---

will appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

It's because your path to attachement is incorrect. Your log clearly points out what you did wrong:

```
/mnt/sdcard/../../data/data/com.example.emailandroid/files//mnt/sdcard/myfile.csv
```

**Never** use hardcoded paths, **never** asume you are 2 leves below the root, **never** traverse directories the way you do in shown code. Use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to get external storage (which does not need to be SD card at all) root and append your **relative** path to get right and valid location.

Comment: now i get error on my file name (myfile). it underline it with red line so i cant debug my app. please help me